# What is default life time of cookies in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

If I have not set any life time in cookies then what is the default life time in cookie?

for e.g

```
setcookie("cookiename", $value);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a cookie via PHP, the default value for its expiration date is 0, which means that the cookie expires when you **close the tab** from the manual:

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session
> (when your browser closes)

Otherwise, you can set the cookies lifetime in seconds as the third parameter:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> **expire**
>
> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

Answer (score 1):

[cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp) with example

If the parameter is not set, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)..

Answer (score 1):

```
When you create a cookie via PHP Default Value is 0

If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at end of the session 
ie when the browser  closes
```

Answer (score 0):

If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php